# CSS Style on table aligns to center

Tags: css, styles, alignment, center, css-tables

After aplying the table styles, the tables are aligned to center, which they should not... Why?

I can provide an HTML file for the following page...
Here's a screenshot: 
[image]
[image]

```
    table.FLTT { 
        clear:both;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #fff;
        border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
        border-bottom:none;}

    table.FLTT th {
        background-color: #4D4D4d!important;
        color: #FFFFFF!important;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: 0.0s;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight:normal;
        }

    table.FLTT td {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
        text-decoration: none;
        }

    table.FLTT tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td {
        background-color: #cccccc;
    }



    table.FLTT tbody tr:hover > td {
        background-color: #222222;
        color: #F0C237;
    }

    table.FLTT tr {
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-transition:all .5s ease;
        -moz-transition:all .5s ease;
        -o-transition:all .5s ease;
        transition:all .5s ease;}

    table.FLTT tr a {
        text-decoration: none;
        outline:none;
        color: #005689;
    }

    table.FLTT tr:hover a{
        background-color: #222222;
        color:#F0C237;
        text-decoration:underline;
    }

    table.FLTT tr.cat-list-row1 {
        background:#eee}

    table.FLTT thead th {
        color:#fff!important;
        background:#4D4D4d!important;}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide HTML too.

Comment: Please approve my below answer if u cool with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `table.FLIT{ }` code you have mentioned as `margin : 0 auto`. 
Instead of this code the element will be centered in the parent element.

In this `margin` property first value for distance from top ane second value for distance from left border. So `auto` will center that element.

You can remove that property and set as

```
margin : 0px 0px;
```

Or add another property

```
float: left;
```

Comment: I needed the float option. The result can be seen here, even the html code I generate is not visible as it's in an iFrame

Comment: I have the HTML code in a file I upload to the customer via FTP. If you like, I can send you that file, but you have to tell me how?

Comment: upload to your Git account and comment me the link to download

Answer (score 0):

The part `margin: 0 auto;` does that, in `table.FLTT{ }`. You should post some html code to be sure, and put it in context.

Answer (score 0):

The style in `table.FLTT{}` there is `margin: 0 auto;`

It means the margin for top and bottom will assign to `0` and left and right will assign as `auto center`.

So please remove `margin:0 auto;`